# Using declared variable in another sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to use my insert query's Id in another query by declaring variable like below. However second query does not see declared variable. How can I use my first insert's Id in second insert query

```
DECLARE @myVariable table (PKProductVariantId INT)
INSERT INTO STProductVariant
(FKProductId,FKProductDetailValueId_,ProductVariantCode,IsActive,StockQuantity)
OUTPUT inserted.PKProductVariantId into @myVariable
values(1,1,'test',1,1)
```

Then

```
insert into STBranchProductVariantRelation(FKProductVariant,FKBranch,IsActive)
values (@myVariable,1,1)
```

Comment: have it done in a stored procedure.

Comment: MySQL does not have table variables or inserted table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into STBranchProductVariantRelation(FKProductVariant, FKBranch, IsActive)
    select t.PKProductVariantId, 1, 1
    from @myVariable t;
```

I think you are confusing your self by naming a *table* variable a "variable".  You are then thinking it is a scalar variable.

I would write this code as:

```
DECLARE @ids table (PKProductVariantId INT);

INSERT INTO STProductVariant
(FKProductId, FKProductDetailValueId_, ProductVariantCode, IsActive, StockQuantity)
    OUTPUT inserted.PKProductVariantId into @ids
    VALUES(1, 1, 'test', 1, 1); 

    insert into STBranchProductVariantRelation(FKProductVariant, FKBranch, IsActive)
        select i.PKProductVariantId, 1, 1
        from @ids i;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the pk from the inserted row in STProductVariant? Try this:

```
INSERT INTO STProductVariant (...) VALUES (...);
SET @lastId := LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO STBranchProductVariantRelation (FKProductVariant, FKBranch, IsActive)
VALUES (@lastId, 1, 1);
```